# Delete specific line number(s) from a text file using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to delete one or more specific line numbers from a file. How would I do this using sed?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To delete lines 2, 12-17 and line 57 from file `data.txt` using `sed` you could do something like this:

```
 sed -e '2d;12,17d;57d' data.txt
```

to create a backup of the original file (with a `.bak` extension) use `-i.bak` with the command.

```
 sed -i.bak -e '2d;12,17d;57d' data.txt
```